# Emails from website goes to my gmail account, but not client's account

Tags: php, email, gmail

I created a website and uploaded it to a free-hosting site to test the php.  When I send test emails from the website and set the receiving address to my gmail email account, I receive them.  Though, they get flagged as spam/phishing (On the emails I have a red warning label).   However, when I set the receiving address to my client's gmail account, he doesn't get them at all, they're not present in his SPAM box (he let me look at his gmail account to confirm).

I'm thinking maybe he has a spamblocker level that my email doesn't have?  Or is this situation occurring because I am using a free-hosting site to send email?  I plan to upload it to GoDaddy. Do you think by uploading it to a paid hosting site will change my situation or would I need PHPMailer?  My question is why do I get the emails, but when I switch the receiving email to my clients', he does not receive them at all?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email-ad'])) {
$email_to = "xxxxxxx1@gmail.com"; //my email
$email_subject = "General Inquiry from xxxxcompany";
function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email-ad']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['intention']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');        
}
$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email-ad']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // required
$intention = $_POST['intention']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required
$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />'; 
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
$error_message .= 'The name that you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Intention: ".clean_string($intention)."\n"; 
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);   
sleep(2);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"5; url=index.html\">";
?>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
 <font color="white">
  <font family="Helvetica">
    <div class="redirect">Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.        You will redirected back to the homepage in a few. </div>
</font>
</font>
</body>
</html> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Impossible to say. The code is useless, since obviously PHP is able to send the email to your other accounts. You'll have to check your mail server logs to see what happened AFTER php handed over the email. Remember: `mail()` is the equivalent of walking an envelope down to the street corner and dropping it into a mailbox. What happens AFTER that is not php's problem.

Comment: in your email works but in your clients email doesn't work, are you sure that the email address that you are writing is correct? it could be the problem, sometimes I write fast a name and I write it wrongly.

Comment: @MarcB: Right.  I just didn't want to leave anything out of the post that was potentially useful.  Thanks for letting me know, though and the education. Too bad I don't think I even have that functionality at this free web-hosting site. Though, I will keep that in mind when I'm debugging to use mail server logs to see what's going on.

Comment: @TiGreX:  Yeah, I thought that was my problem at first, but I made sure by copying and pasting the email address into the where I needed to put it.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is most likely occurring due to using a free-hosting service. Keep in mind that it is more likely to have spammers on shared web hosting due to the nature of it: many users using the same IP address to send mail from. Also, as it is a free-hosting service, everyone could send e-mails and therefore also spam.

By the way, like you said, some e-mail providers use quite aggressive spam blocking, so that could be the reason your client didn't receive your e-mail at all.

Comment: Ok, I see.  It's not the code, it's the space that I'm using that may be causing the problem.  I'm going to upload to a paid hosting site and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: You can check if an IP address or domain name is listed in the Spamhaus blacklist [here](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/).

Comment: Wow that was an eye-opener. I have 4 tests sites up on that service, just trying to see which php cocktail would work. Through Spamhaus, while two of them of the ips associated with the account weren't on any of the lists, the other two were.   One ip address was spewing spam trojans!  Crazy...yep, this is a pretty cool tool. Thank you for sharing!